# Basis formed by three non-coplanar vectors.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Suppose $\bf p, q, r$ are three non-coplanar vectors in ${\mathbb{R^3}}$. There is a vector $\bf x$ having projections along them are $a, b$ and $c$ respectively. Then can we write
$$
\bf x = a\bf p + b\bf q + c\bf r
$$? If yes, why?

I think this cannot be done unless all three vectors are mutually perpendicular unit vectors.

Comment: By “projection” do you mean specifically _orthogonal_ projection? If so, then see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035114/why-scalar-projection-does-not-yield-coordinates/2035131#2035131.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not true. Take$$\mathbf p=\left(1,1,0\right),\ \mathbf q=\left(1,0,1\right)\text{, and }\mathbf r=\left(0,1,1\right)$$and $\mathbf x=(1,1,1)$. Then $a=b=c=1$, but $a\mathbf p+b\mathbf q+c\mathbf q=(2,2,2)\neq\mathbf x$.

Yes, if you want that the equality holds, then the vectors $\mathbf p$, $\mathbf q$, and $\mathbf r$ should be orthogonal.

Comment: Sir , does this hold true if it's given that **a** , **b** and **c** are not just three non-coplanar vectors , but also that they are three non-coplanar **unit** vectors ?

Comment: @An_Elephant In this question, $a$, $b$, and $c$ are numbers, not vectors.

Comment: Oops sorry. I meant **p** , **q** and **r** instead.

Comment: @An_Elephant In that case, yes.

Comment: Thanks sir for the reply. I asked this question yesterday but they are saying that answer is no in general. Can you please have a look at this : 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4851160/1020656

Comment: @An_Elephant My bad. Yes, hey have to be orthogonal (besides being unit vectors).

Comment: Okay. Thanks sir for the confirmation.