# Is a vector equal to the vector sum of it's components along any three non-coplanar unit vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Suppose $a,b$ and $c$ are the components of a vector **P** along three non-coplanar unit vectors **A**, **B** and **C** respectively. Then, is the below equality true ?

$$\textbf{P}=a\textbf{A}+b\textbf{B}+c\textbf{C}$$

I know that it's true if :

$$\textbf{A}=\hat{i}$$
$$\textbf{B}=\hat{j}$$
$$\textbf{C}=\hat{k}$$

where $\hat{i},\hat{j},\hat{k}$ are unit vectors along $x,y$ and $z$ axis respectively. But I am not sure if this holds for any general case (like what if these unit vectors are not perpendicular etc. etc. ).

**Context:**

My textbook assumed the above equality true in general to solve a question which was to prove that :

$$\vec{p}\times\vec{q}=\vec{a}[a\space p\space q] +\vec{b}[b\space p\space q] +\vec{c}[c\space p \space q].  $$

where $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are any three coplanar unit vectors and $[x\space y\space z]$ denotes the scalar triple product.

Here's the original :

[image: meow]

Comment: How do you define a "component" of a vector? In three dimensions, any three non-coplanar vectors $A,B,C$ span the whole space. so any other vector $P$ can be written as a sum $P=aA+bB+cC$. Then you might want to call $a,b,c$ "components" of $P$, but it is not necessary to use that word in order to write the sum. I think there are some steps in your book that you have left out of the question.

Comment: By saying component , I mean the projection. Like the component of $\vec{a}$ on $\vec{b}$ is $\vec{a}.\hat{b}$

Comment: In general you cannot use projection to find components of a vector over a non-orthonormal basis. (The vectors must not only be orthogonal, but all unit length in order to use projection.) I suggest you go back a paragraph or two (or three or more) in the book to find out **exactly** what it is saying, and if that doesn't clear up the question, edit the full context into the question.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks. I only know basic vectors to use in physics. I'll post a picture to clarify.

Comment: That really does clarify the question immensely. When I see something in a textbook that looks wrong to me, the probability is high that the error is mine, so I go through the steps I described. But sometimes a textbook author just tells a whopper. It looks like we have one of those cases here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: although any three non-coplanar vectors can form a *basis* for a three-dimensional vector space (meaning you can always write $P = aA + bB + cC$ where $A,B,C$ are the three basis vectors and $P$ is any other vector),
in general, projection onto the basis vectors gives the components of a vector (the numbers $a,b,c$) only in the case of an orthonormal basis, not when the basis is any arbitrary set of non-coplanar vectors.

The argument in the book is wrong and it is not hard to find a counterexample to the "fact" that they claim to have proved.

Here is a counterexample:
\begin{align}
\vec a &= (1, 0, 0), \\
\vec b &= \left(\tfrac1{\sqrt2}, \tfrac1{\sqrt2}, 0\right), \\
\vec c &= \left(\tfrac1{\sqrt2}, 0, \tfrac1{\sqrt2}\right), \\
\vec p &= (2, 3, 4), \\
\vec q &= (-1, 2, 1), \\
[\vec a,\vec p,\vec q] &= -5, \\
[\vec b,\vec p,\vec q] &= -\tfrac{11}{\sqrt2}, \\
[\vec c,\vec p,\vec q] &= \sqrt2, \\
[\vec a,\vec p,\vec q] \vec a 
+ [\vec b,\vec p,\vec q] \vec b 
+ [\vec c,\vec p,\vec q] \vec c 
&= -5(1, 0, 0)
   + \left(-\tfrac{11}{\sqrt2}\right)
     \left(\tfrac1{\sqrt2}, \tfrac1{\sqrt2}, 0\right)
   + \sqrt2 \left(\tfrac1{\sqrt2}, 0, \tfrac1{\sqrt2}\right) \\
&= (-5, 0, 0) + \left(-\tfrac{11}{2}, -\tfrac{11}{2}, 0\right) + (1, 0, 1) \\
&= \left(-\tfrac{19}{2}, -\tfrac{11}{2}, 1\right),
\end{align}

but
$$
\vec p \times \vec q = (-5, -6,  7).
$$

They claimed the formula always works and here is an example where it clearly doesn't.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know about basis. But thanks for the answer. Can you add a proof also?

Comment: To show that a claim is false, a single counterexample is a proof. Done.

Comment: Does the difference between projections and components has todo with co- contravariants coordinates ?

Comment: @QuantumPotatoïd I don't see a connection, but maybe someone else can. You can get components in a non-orthogonal unit basis by projecting parallel to the plane of the other two basis vectors. For an orthonormal basis that plane is orthogonal to the basis vector, so the projection is orthogonal. If the basis vectors aren't orthogonal, neither is the plane and you get an oblique projection.

Answer (score 0):

Comment:

Two vectors and its resultant are *always* co-planar and define that plane. An addition of a fourth vector could enclose or span a twisted surface among them.

Any vector can be resolved into three components (of non-unit length) generally  along three mutually perpendicular vectors. These three non-unit length vectored components define a plane.

For example a vector of length 13 along the diagonal of a parallelopiped has unit projections along the three axes

$$ 3\hat{i}+4\hat{j}+12\hat{k}$$

If the 3 parts are laid in a single straight line total length is $19,\text{always}>13$.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question. Also, Three vectors are not always co-planar in general.

Comment: Apology if taken to be in general. With one  resultant and two component vectors is the situation discussed here.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether the vectors are perpendicular or not, any vector $R$ can be expressed in terms of three other non coplanar unit vectors in a 3-D space. So yes, the equality does hold.
As a matter of fact, these vectors don't need to be unit vectors either.

Comment: Thanks but My question is not that if a vector can be expressed as such. My question is reverse. In other words, I'm asking for proof of the converse of the theorem you're stating.

Comment: What do you mean by the converse of the theorem?

Comment: Ok sorry. You're going right . But please prove your statement. Don't just state that.

Comment: But the top answer contradicts this.